# Pear installation from ant build

Tags: php, ant, hudson, jenkins

I am setting up CI for a PHP project. Since CI is on cloud I don't have physical access to system.
My ant  target phpunit fails with message -

```
Cannot run program "phpunit": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
```

And I have been told that I need to - "add an extra build step prior to and invocation to install pear and php build tools."
I know I can do - "pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit " but I don't have physical access to CI system and pear installation has to take place from build file.

The build file I used is the one which is available at - jenkins-php.org
How do I add this extra step to build file (I am not knowledgeable of php)

Answer (score 1):

ok this was simple. It could be done by executing shell commands from job configuration page.